# Regular expression for two consecutive things in my case

Tags: java, regex

What is the regular expression matches exactly two consecutive tab and new line symbols. `\t\n\t\n` ? I am using Java.

Comment: Why not just `"\t\n\t\n"`?

Comment: Or `"(\\t\\n){2}"`

Comment: windows line breaks is `\r\n`. So maybe `(\\t(\\r|)\\n){2}`

Comment: I am seeking a way without repeatedly typing "\t\n\t\n"

Comment: `"(\t\n){2}"` if you prefer, but you're not saving yourself any keystrokes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8 supports use of `\R` as a [Linebreak matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that will match **any Unicode linebreak sequence**.

So you can use it like this:

```
String str = "\t\r\n\t\r\n";
System.out.printf("Matched: <%s>%n", str.matches("(?:\\t\\R){2}"));

str = "\t\n\t\n";
System.out.printf("Matched: <%s>%n", str.matches("(?:\\t\\R){2}"));
```

Since we are using this regex in `matches()` method here hence it will match full string input only.

**Output:**

```
Matched: <true>
Matched: <true>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your expression will match `\t\n\t\n` even if it is part of a longer sequence, i.e. not exactly two consecutive occurrences.

If you would like to match the sequence of exactly two `\t\n`s, use negative look-around:

```
(?<!\t\n)(\t\n){2}(?!\t\n)
```

Note the use of parentheses and `{2}`, it lets you avoid typing the same sequence multiple times.